# IOSDriver cannot perform sendKey Enter on IOS Safari

Tags: java, ios, appium

```
My scenarios:

1.Start Safari on Iphone
2.Navigate to "https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
3.Click on icon Search
4.Type text "Apple" and Enter
```

[> Step 4 Image <](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTDgd.png)

**I'm using Java Appium.**
**At step 4, Text "Apple" is typed BUT Enter Key cannot perform to send.**
**Could someone help resolving this issue. My code:**

```
    ....
    AppiumDriver iosDriver = new IOSDriver(new URL(driverUrl), cap);
    ....
    iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"search mw-ui-background-icon-search\"]")).sendKeys("Apple");
    iosDriver.getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Put "Keys.ENTER" after sendKeys "Apple" + Keys.ENTER

```
....
AppiumDriver iosDriver = new IOSDriver(new URL(driverUrl), cap);
....
iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"search mw-ui-background-icon-search\"]")).sendKeys("Apple" + Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work with javascript executor.

driver.execute_script("var a = document.getElementById('element_location_id'); a.focus(); a.value='10';")